# It method not taking js: true in Rails testing setup with Minitest, Capybara, and PhantomJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, phantomjs, minitest

Hi there I am running a Rails 3.2.21 app with the following Gemfile:

```
  group :test, :development do
    gem "minitest-rails-capybara"
    gem "capybara_minitest_spec"
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'turn'
    gem 'guard'
    gem 'guard-minitest'
    gem 'poltergeist'
    gem 'phantomjs', :require => 'phantomjs/poltergeist'
  end
```

And I have a test/minitest_helper.rb file like this:

```
    ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
    require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
    require "minitest/autorun"
    require "capybara/rails"
    # require "active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown"

    # MiniTest::Spec
    class MiniTest::Spec
      include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
      include Capybara::DSL
    end


    class IntegrationTest < MiniTest::Spec
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
      include Capybara::DSL
      register_spec_type(/test$/, self)
    end

    Turn.config.format = :outline

    Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
        Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :phantomjs => Phantomjs.path)
    end
```

whenever I tried to run a test to test out whether an HTML page contains a certain word generated by some javascript under test/features/order_test.rb

```
  require 'minitest_helper'

  describe "Simple Order Form" do
    it "display selected file names after user selects files", js: true do
      visit order_v3_path
      page.must_have_content('drop')
    end
  end
```

It complains that the "it" method takes only 0..1 arguments

```
/Users/nik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/spec.rb:201:in `it': wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1) (ArgumentError)
```

How does one go about finding out where the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec), js: true should be in describe block.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this inside your specific test where you want to use js instead of , `js: true do` .

```
 Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
```